# cron job does not execute in docker container

Tags: docker, cron

Putting together solutions from various previous answers to the topic, and I am still failing. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
    FROM python:3.7

    RUN apt-get update &&\
        apt-get install -y cron &&\
        apt-get clean

    # do this now to use layer cache mechanism
    COPY requirements.txt /
    RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt


    RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/src/app
    WORKDIR /usr/local/src/app

    ADD script .
    ADD StockLogger.py .
    ADD crontab.txt .
    COPY entry.sh .

    RUN chmod 755 script entry.sh && touch /var/log/cron.log

    CMD ./entry.sh && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Here is the entry.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh
    set -e

    # start cron
    service cron start

    cp ./crontab.txt /etc/cron.d/

    #fix link-count, as cron is being a pain, and docker is making hardlink count >0 (very high)
    touch /etc/crontab /etc/cron.*/*

    echo Added crontab
    whoami
    echo ***entry.sh done***
```

Here is crontab.txt

```
    SHELL=/bin/sh
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

    * * * * *   root    echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
    # Keeping the empty next line
```

When I run the container with `docker run sprevrha/crontester:latest`, the `tail -f` in the `CMD` keeps it nicely running, but doesn't produce any output. The file is also empty when I exec into the running container and inspect it with `cat` . Also, `crontab -l` says there are no cron jobs for root. The `/etc/cron.d/crontab.txt` is there, and it is owned by root.

```
    root@16d01a1a2c0c:/usr/local/src/app# ls -l /etc/cron.d                                      
    total 4                                                                                      
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1020 Jan  7 21:20 crontab.txt
```

Link count is 1, so presumably ok.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the cron daemon actually running?  You should probably make `crond`, not `tail`, be the main container process, which involves directly running it as a foreground process and not launching it via `service`.  (I'm suspicious that you start cron and then afterwards do some fixups to make it work.)

Comment: Indeed, I start cron with ```service cron start```. When I query it interactively, I get the response that the service cron running. Would I need to run crond as well?

Comment: Nope. If `service cron status` says `[OK]`, it is running. No need for crond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only from reading a little bit documentation, it does not support any dots and suffixes like *.txt* and its path is directly under */etc/*

> From documentation:
>   /etc/cron.d/  Put all scripts here and call them from /etc/crontab file.

Comment: OK I figured out. For my configuration, your answer partially applies. Indeed the files under /etc/crontab cannot have dots in their names, so I renamed mine to `mycrontab`. However I did not have to change `/etc/crontab`. See [this answer on Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458713/how-are-files-under-etc-cron-d-used).

Comment: I am glad that it was helping to find correct way. Yes, i got your point, so basically any name will work, just dots and suffixes are not accepted. I changed also my answer little bit to correct it for future users.